# SQL - Comparing dates efficiently for specific IDs

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two DB's that look like this:

**Table 1**

| ID | time1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21.3.2000, 16:00 |
| 1 | 21.3.2000, 17:00 |
| ... | ... |
| 2 | 21.3.2000, 16:00 |
| ... | ... |

**Table 2**

| ID | time2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21.3.2000, 16:30 |
| 1 | 21.3.2000, 18:00 |
| ... | ... |
| 2 | 21.3.2000, 15:30 |
| ... | ... |

where for each `ID` I have several dates `time1` and `time2`.
For each `time1` I want the closest `time2` which is also not greater than `time1`.
I tried that but even building the carthesian product like this:

```sql
SELECT h."ID", h."time", m."time"
FROM Table1 as h, Table2 as m
WHERE h."ID" = m."ID"
```

loads for a very long time because of the huge amount of data, is there any way I can improve the speed and get the same result?

Comment: Does your application allow you to limit the time range? Can you say "For each `time1` I want the closest `time2` within two hours of `time1`" or some such limit?

Comment: That might work, not ideal but if I'm generous with the timeframe it should be okay, if you have example code in mind would you share it with me please?

Comment: you're right, time2 should be in table2, my bad

Comment: If time1 is say `21.3.2000, 16:00` do you only want to consider times that are greater than it or would you also consider lesser time e.g. `21.3.2000, 15:45` vs `21.3.2000, 16:30`?

Comment: I'd like to match the closest one to time1 but not greater than time1, I should definitly add that to the question!

Comment: What are the data types for time1 and time2 ? (they don't look like timestamps to me ...)

Comment: they are timestamps, this was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that time2 could be greater than or equal to time1... that simplifies the logic. I would try a lateral join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID = table1.ID AND table2.time2 >= table1.time1
    ORDER BY table2.time2
    LIMIT 1
) AS table2_new ON true
```

Comment: I've found the exact idea in this articel https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/869b6f3f-a757-4a03-8704-96e4df734e29/find-closest-date-to-another-date?forum=transactsql five minutes ago and I was wondering why it is so fast, thanks so much for the answer, could you give a brief explaination why this is so much faster than doing the carthesian product and then filtering? Is it only because we cut the length for the second table or is there more to it?

Comment: To be honest this is what I use in SQL Server for queries such as these (over there it is called TOP 1 and OUTER APPLY). These are used instead of simple joins because the logic is straight forward. Performance, for reasons unknown to me, is very good. But It is obvious that lateral joins do not generate a m x n cross product.

Comment: I've heard until now that thinking about performance in SQL is not that important because of the great compiler, that's why I think it's mostly the cross product as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I'll look more into the different kinds of joins, are there any ones in particular you think are usefull like this, noob here as you can see ^^

Comment: Just focus on INNER and OUTER. LATERAL are used only in a handful of cases such as this.